# RDP errors out trying to login windows 2008 server SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, service, terminal

I try to RDP into windows 2008 SP2, box from anything (vista, server 2008, windows 7) and get this error on the login process

the terminal connection is currently busy processing a connect, disconnect, reset or delete operation,

I can't seem to get to it, any ideas short of rebooting or killing any open sessions?

What is a good way to diagnose this problem not much out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following via CMD.exe:

```
qwinsta /server:[windows 2008 sp2 box]
```

where [windows 2008 sp2 box] is the DNS or IP address of the box you're trying to RDP into.

This should tell you what the open sessions are.  Please post that information here.

If you find a particular session that you want to kill explicitly, take note of the ID that is shown for it and use the following command to execute the kill:

```
logoff [id] /server:[windows 2008 sp2 box]
```

Comment: +1 but only works for if both system are either in the same workgroup, or same domain. I could not list sessions on domain server from non-domain joined workstation even using domain credentials (2k3, 2k8 x32/x64, 2k8 R2) . It could just be my setup though!

Comment: If you have access to the windows 2008 box, try going to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Terminal Services Manager.  This may be called something else in 2008, but there is a tool that shows you connections and connection state.

Comment: I tried this from several other machines, just no response.  I even trying the avocent (KVM over IP) and it was hung, I ended up having to you LILO (HP) to reboot box and it now works, looks like RDP or RPC or somthing maybe explorer hung.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer cause it does show data relavent but my particular issue was that somthing was hung and it needed a reboot.

Comment: weird, have never seen that before...well, good news is that you can get into the box now